# JavaScript: Convert array to object without key or string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like `[1,2,3,4,5]`. I want to convert it to object like `{1,2,3,4,5}` or `1,2,3,4,5`.

I would be thankful if someone helps me.

Comment: That's not possible. `{1,2,3,4,5}` isn't valid

Comment: what about 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: What do you mean with _"object without key"_? How would you access the elements.

Comment: I want to send parameter to api url. with array it looks like this: /some?a[]=[1,2,3,4,5] but i want it like:  /some?a=1,2,3,4,5

Comment: You want to convert an array `[1,2,3,4,5]` to a string `'1,2,3,4,5'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `1,2,3,4,5`, you just have to use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(arr.join())
```

Also, specifically for query parameters, in browser or Node, you could use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), which helps you define your query object

```js
const obj = { a: [1,2,3,4,5] }
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(obj).toString();

console.log(searchParams)
```